# Angular6 File Upload (Image) with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, angular6

I have a problem when uploading an image in angular 6.

Angular:

```
addAvatar(username: string, file: File) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    });

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/addavatar/` + username, formData, {headers});
  }
```

Spring controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addavatar/{username}")
public ResponseEntity<?> addAvatar(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username, @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    return userService.addAvatar(username, file);
}
```

If I send request in Postman all works, but if I want to send request in Angular then I have a 404.

[File Upload in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCfZq.jpg)
[Response in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57u1f.jpg)

Comment: '/file/' path in Postman URL seems to overlooked in angular request path API_URL.

Answer (score 0):

`/file/` URI in Postman URL seems to be overlooked at Angular request path literal `API_URL`. That's why it occurs the 404 error.